Using Python I am having problems uploading files to Workday via the put_worker_document operation
I have been hitting my head against this for a while now.  I am trying to use the put_worker_document operation of workday's staffing endpoint:
https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service//Staffing/v42.0"/>
I wrote 2 scripts, one using a pythonic methodology w/ the zeep library and another using the raw xml.  I can't get either script to work.
Below are my scripts, and their corresponding output errors.
first script: pythonic objects w/ zeep -
import base64
from zeep import Client, Settings
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
from zeep.helpers import serialize_object

# Workday SOAP endpoint and WSDL URL
wsdl = 'https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/<my tenant>/Staffing/v42.0?wsdl'
endpoint = 'https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/<my tenant>/Staffing/v42.0'

# Authentication credentials
username = '<my user name>'
password = '<my password>'

# Initialize the zeep client with the WSDL
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, wsse=UsernameToken(username, password), settings=settings)

# Define namespaces
ns = {
    'bsvc': 'urn:com.workday/bsvc'
}

# Read the file and encode it in Base64
file_path = r'd:/path\to\file.pdf'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    file_content = base64.b64encode(file.read()).decode('utf-8')

# Prepare the request payload
worker_reference = {
    'ID': [
        {
            'type': 'WID',
            'ID': '<worker id>'  # Replace with actual worker ID
        }
    ]
}

document_category_reference = {
    'ID': [
        {
            'type': 'WID',
            'ID': '<category id>'  # Replace with actual document category ID
        }
    ]
}

document_data = {
    # 'ID': 'document_id',  # or omit if creating a new document
    'Filename': 'file.pdf',
    'Comment': 'Uploaded via API Test 1',
    'File': file_content,
    'Document_Category_Reference': document_category_reference,
    'Worker_Reference': worker_reference,
    'Content_Type': 'application/pdf'  # Make sure this matches your file type
}

document_request = {
    'Worker_Document_Data': document_data
}

# Call the Put_Worker_Document operation
response = client.service.Put_Worker_Document(**document_request)

# Serialize and print the response
response_serialized = serialize_object(response)
print(response_serialized)

error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\BFAS ADP\work\wdc_put_doc4.py", line 64, in <module>
    response = client.service.Put_Worker_Document(Worker_Document_Data=document_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 46, in __call__
    return self._proxy._binding.send(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 123, in send
    envelope, http_headers = self._create(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 73, in _create
    serialized = operation_obj.create(*args, **kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py", line 224, in create
    return self.input.serialize(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 73, in serialize
    body_value = self.body(*args, **kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 58, in __call__
    instance = self.type(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 75, in __call__
    return self._value_class(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 106, in __init__
    items = _process_signature(self._xsd_type, args, kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 220, in _process_signature
    values = element.parse_kwargs(kwargs, None, available_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\indicators.py", line 219, in parse_kwargs
    sub_result = element.parse_kwargs(kwargs, elm_name, available_kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 135, in parse_kwargs
    return self.type.parse_kwargs(kwargs, name or self.attr_name, available_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 338, in parse_kwargs
    value = self._create_object(value, name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 362, in _create_object
    return self(**value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 75, in __call__
    return self._value_class(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 106, in __init__
    items = _process_signature(self._xsd_type, args, kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 220, in _process_signature
    values = element.parse_kwargs(kwargs, None, available_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\indicators.py", line 219, in parse_kwargs
    sub_result = element.parse_kwargs(kwargs, elm_name, available_kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 135, in parse_kwargs
    return self.type.parse_kwargs(kwargs, name or self.attr_name, available_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 338, in parse_kwargs
    value = self._create_object(value, name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 362, in _create_object
    return self(**value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 75, in __call__
    return self._value_class(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 106, in __init__
    items = _process_signature(self._xsd_type, args, kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 220, in _process_signature
    values = element.parse_kwargs(kwargs, None, available_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\indicators.py", line 219, in parse_kwargs
    sub_result = element.parse_kwargs(kwargs, elm_name, available_kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 135, in parse_kwargs
    return self.type.parse_kwargs(kwargs, name or self.attr_name, available_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 338, in parse_kwargs
    value = self._create_object(value, name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 356, in _create_object
    return [self._create_object(val, name) for val in value]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 362, in _create_object
    return self(**value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 75, in __call__
    return self._value_class(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 106, in __init__
    items = _process_signature(self._xsd_type, args, kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User1\python312\Lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 241, in _process_signature
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: {urn:com.workday/bsvc}Document_Category__All_ObjectIDType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ID'. Signature: `xsd:string, type: {urn:com.workday/bsvc}Document_Category__All_ReferenceEnumeration`

Now, second script where I try and send the raw xml:
import base64
from zeep import Client, Settings, Transport
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests import Session
from lxml import etree

# Workday SOAP endpoint and WSDL URL
wsdl = 'https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/<my tenant>/Staffing/v42.0?wsdl'
endpoint = 'https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/<my tenant>/Staffing/v42.0'

# Authentication credentials
username = '<my username>'
password = '<my password>'

# Initialize the zeep client with the WSDL
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
transport = Transport(session=session)
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport, settings=settings)

# Read the file and encode it in Base64
file_path = r'd:\path\to\file.pdf'

with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    file_content = base64.b64encode(file.read()).decode('utf-8')

# Create the raw XML request
raw_xml = f"""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bsvc:Put_Worker_Document_Request>
         <bsvc:Worker_Document_Data>
            <bsvc:ID></bsvc:ID>
            <bsvc:Filename>file.pdf</bsvc:Filename>
            <bsvc:Comment>Uploaded via API Test 1</bsvc:Comment>
            <bsvc:File>{file_content}</bsvc:File>
            <bsvc:Document_Category_Reference>
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID"><category id></bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Document_Category_Reference>
            <bsvc:Worker_Reference>
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="WID"><employee id></bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Worker_Reference>
            <bsvc:Content_Type>application/pdf</bsvc:Content_Type>
         </bsvc:Worker_Document_Data>
      </bsvc:Put_Worker_Document_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""

# Parse the raw XML string
parsed_xml = etree.fromstring(raw_xml)

# Define headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction': 'urn:com.workday/bsvc#Put_Worker_Document'  # Replace with the correct SOAP action if necessary
}
# Send the raw XML request
response = client.transport.post_xml(address=endpoint, envelope=parsed_xml, headers=headers)
print(f"Response: {response}")


# Print the response
# print(etree.tostring(response.content, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))

error output:
All I get on this script is a 500 response.
I don't care how I get it to work I need to get this working, I hope someone can provide some guidance.  workday doesn't provide much or good   documentation.
Thanks.

I think error is on this line :             'ID': ''  # Replace with actual worker ID

@jdweng What do you mean? what do you think the error is? Do you have any ideas as to the solution?

What values are you using for the ID?
